# Google analytics user tracking UserID string

Tags: php, google-analytics

I need to track users coming to my website. Currently I'm getting information for all users and this is no good. I don't want to know personal information, I just want to create a unique string, that identify's a single unique user. Reading the google developers documentation, I'm having trouble implementing this on the website.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

UserID

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
      <?php
      // New Google Analytics code to set User ID.
      // $userId is a unique, persistent, and non-personally identifiable string ID.
      if (isset($userId)) {
      $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'userId': '%s'});";
      echo sprintf($gacode, $userId);
      }     
      else {
      $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');";
      echo sprintf($gacode);
      }?>
      ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Is the UserID string corrent, google is telling me the UserID is a `unique, persistent, and non-personally identifiable string ID` is this correct, or does the userId string need to be different from %s

All I need to get is a random number and 1/2 letters to identify a single user. ***So for example, 1234DK = User 1***

Comment: well if you send '%s' all the time isn't that going to mean that everyone is the same user?  You are going to have to change the user for different people.    Note: this is an internal value you wont actually be able to see it in the website you know that right?

Comment: @DalmTo hi, yes, just after realizing this. I created a piece of code to generate a random number and placed the variable where the 'userId' should be. Have you got any good advice on the unique string I should use to record this information? Is there good/bad practices that I should/shouldn't be using?

Comment: My applications are mostly installed aplications I normally do md5 on on the PCs mac address. you could maybe MD5 there Ip address.   I think the undocumented limit is 40 char, however its hard to prove that since we cant actually see it.

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo for this useful information!

Comment: Actually, my recommended "best practice" is to set the userId when user login - and when they log in we look up  some persistent identifier e.g. their email or the client id in the dBase. If you do your md5 hash this way you get cross-device tracking for free. Which is what UserId tracking about in the first place